# WPF cannot select items in ListView

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, listview, binding

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXQGg.png)

i have a grid as shown in screenshot above. The grid is coloured green.

Inside the grid i have a listview, it is coloured red.

I cannot select the rows inside the listview. The entire list view will register a mouse enter event. But only the bottom half of the listview registers a mouse down event.

Inside the listview is the gridview. It contains a checkbox and a label. None of these register mouse enter events. Any suggestions on why i cant select rows in list or intereact with checkbox ?

Comment: share your xaml

Comment: There's no XAML for us to inspect :( ? Now,let me make a few assumptions...maybe in your xaml,if u are databinding anything, maybe you are doing it the wrong way. Now,if u don't see any items selected when you select them , why not change the color of an item to inspect if they are selected or not...... ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was verticle alignment top on listview

```
    <Grid  Name="CheckedListBoxItemHelperGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource CheckedListBoxItemHelperViewSource}" Background="#FF1FCD2F">
    <ListView BorderBrush="#c2c2c2"  Height="318" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,38,10,0" Name="CheckedListBoxItemHelperListView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFA62020">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```